# Could not build the precompiled application for the device

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-analytics

I am using MacOS Monterey and facing issue in my flutter app after installation of Firebase Analytics dependency I've also tried previous versions of Firebase Analytics but same issue

```
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initWithPattern:options:error:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initMessageInfoFn

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$isAppActive

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$transactionDate

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$isFreeTrial

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setTimeZone:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$purchaseDateIA5String

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$dateFromString:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:error:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setResourceValue:forKey:error:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$maxParametersPerFilter

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$maxFiltersPerAudience

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$timeIntervalSinceDate:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$initWithLocaleIdentifier:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$isValidArrayParamItem:failureCode:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$currentImplementationForClass:selector:isClassSelector:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$swizzleClass:selector:isClassSelector:withBlock:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$shouldAllowClickID

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$handleDeepLink:clickTimestampInMs:eventTimestampInSeconds:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$handleOpenURL:clickTimestampInMs:eventTimestampInSeconds:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$application:openURL:options:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$sendDeepLinkURLToAppDelegateOnMainThread:extraInfo:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$deepLinkInfoFromResponseData:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$isDeferredDeepLinkEnabled

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$deferredDeepLinkRetryCount

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$maxDeferredDeepLinkRetryCount

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$SKANFetchRetryLimit

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$convertCoarseConversionValueFromProtoValue:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setSKANEvaluationUpdateBackoffMillis:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$maybeScheduleSKANCVFetchRetry

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$handleSKANFetchResponse:data:error:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setIsSKANRequestInProgress:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setSKANDelayAlarm:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$SKANFirstWindowCVFetchDelay

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$SKANDelayAlarm

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$SKANEvaluationEventTimeMillis

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$SKANEvaluationUpdateBackoffMillis

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$purchaseType

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$SKANFirstWindowCVFetchRetryLimit

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$SKANCVFetchRetryLimit

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _SKAdNetworkCoarseConversionValueMedium

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _SKAdNetworkCoarseConversionValueHigh

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$allEventAggregates:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$analyticsAccountTimeZoneOffsetMinutes

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$samplingRateForEvent:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$isEventBundledAfterRoll:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$publicEventCount:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$createRawEventMetadataWithUserAttributes:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$unmatchedFirstOpenWithoutIDFA

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _SKAdNetworkCoarseConversionValueLow

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$logFirstOpenConsentedEvent:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$deleteRawEventsOverAbsoluteLimit:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$insertRawEvent:metadataFingerprint:isRealtime:error:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$maybeAddDebugAndRealtimeParameters:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$resetWithNewDay:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$maxEventsPerDay

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$maxPublicEventsPerDay

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$insertIfNotDuplicateSubscriptionID:error:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$safelistedEvents

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$firebaseInstallationID

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$sessionStitchingTokenWithSessionNumber:sessionExpired:userIDAvailable:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$appVersionMajor

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$isRealtimeEvent:dailyCounts:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$eesFeatureEnabled

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$editEvent

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$hasCreatedEvents

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$eventContext

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$eventAfterSafelistingEvent:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$query

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$dedupeSubscriptionEvent:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$processEventOnWorkerQueue:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$shouldDropDuplicatedSessionStartWithRolloutEvent:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$applyParameters:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$monitoringSamplePeriod

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setLastMonitorDataSampledTimestamp:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$incrementLastBundleIndex

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$copyWithPreviousTimestamp:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$incrementCurrentBundleCount

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$incrementCurrentSessionCount

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$updateEventAggregates:error:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$evaluateFiltersForEvent:eventAggregates:audienceTimestampsCache:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$isEventBlocklisted:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$removeObjectsAtIndexes:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$updateDailyCounts:error:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$incrementRealtimeCountsForCurrentDay:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$persistedConfig

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$decrementAllEventsCount

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$setConversion:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$updateLifetimeValueWithEvent:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$maxConversionsPerDay

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$containsRawEventWithMetadataFingerprint:error:

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _objc_msgSend$rawEventsWithMetadataFingerprint:


Error launching application on Faiz’s iPhone.
```